# How to allow third party cookies on edge driver options in selenium

Tags: selenium-edgedriver

I can not find option to allow third party cookies in edge driver something like profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies which we use for chrome driver

I tried with Edge options, set experimental option and providing profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies with value 0.

Got unrecognised ms edge option, sessionnotcreatedexception